# Inbound SMS restrictions for Twilio trial accounts

Tags: twilio, sms, messaging

I'm having some trouble getting Twilio's inbound SMS to work and I'm wondering if it's because I'm on a trial account or if I have something misconfigured.

I have two handlers for inbound messaging. One is a webhook to a publicly accessible URL, the second is to a simple flow that replies an acknowledgement (built using a Twilio provided template) - neither are getting called.

What am I missing? This seems like a simple use case scenario but I'm really at a loss of what might be wrong.

I have sent messages from both a verified and unverified number. Neither trigger a handler, nor are they logged in the "Programmable Messaging Logs" as errors or otherwise. At the very least I would expect to see an entry in the logs that an inbound message was received, even if it was discarded before handing over to the handlers.

Comment: What happens when you call the phone numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was a configuration error on my part. The phone number was part of a Messaging Service that was setup to swallow all incoming messages. I'm new to Twilio and didn't realize that this is the default for new Messaging Services.